# Retry a request until result returns a value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an API that is requesting some data from a backend service.

The data might not be their at the time of the first request. So, i want to retry 5 times until it the data present.

I know the data is present when the array returned to me is not empty

**Get Classification Result**

```
 public async processClassification(instanceId: any, requestId: any): Promise<any> {

        const url = this.config.backendUrl + "/check/classification";

        const options = {
            uri: url,
            headers: {
                "X-IDCHECK-SESSION_ID": instanceId,
            },
            body: {},
            json: true,
            resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        };

        let classification;

        try {

            classification = await request.get(options);

            if (classification.statusCode !== 200) {
                return {
                    success: false,
                    error: classification,
                    message: "Failed to process classification",
                };
            }

            return {
                success: true,
                data: classification,
                message: "Successfully processed classification",
            };

        } catch (err) {

            return {
                success: false,
                error: err.stack,
                message: "Server threw an unexpected error during processClassification",
            };

        }

    }
```

Above is a simple function which queries the backend http once to get the classification result. The array `result.body.data.classification` will be empty if there are no results.

How can i adapt this code to retry up to 5 times.

Please don't be put off by the typescript, i will accept js answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion to call the function again if the request returns no data, passing the number of attempts.

If the number of attempts exceeds the max times then eventually `throw` an error.

```js
// Mock request, resolves filled array if value is 5, 
// resolves empty array otherwise.
const request = value => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      value === 5 ? resolve(['foo', 'bar']) : resolve([])
    }, 500)
  })
}

const retry = async (times, attempts = 0) => {
  attempts++
 
  console.log('Attempt', attempts)
 
  const result = await request(attempts)
  
  if (result.length) {
    return result
  } else {
    if (attempts >= times)
      throw new Error('Max attempts exceeded')

    return retry(times, attempts)
  }
}

retry(5)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Is there some library that does this?

Comment: I came across this https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-retry but it doesent allow to state when you should retry

Comment: I have no idea, but it's trivial to build your own function that does this. See post.

Answer (score -1):

You might try this  package https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-promise-retry .

Comment: I already use the following package -https://github.com/request/request-promise-nativedoes it mean i would have to switch?